# iOS: How to make NSBundle pathForResource retrieve localizable contents from its subpath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, foundation

I have this code below in hope that it would locate the Localizable.strings file under contents folder, but it always searches directly under the application bundle and returns a full path without the "contents" folder in it.

What do I need to do to get the intended behavior?

Note: If I create a folder reference, I get "Could not inspect the application package."

```
NSString *customFolder = @"contents";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Localizable"
                                           ofType:@"strings"
                                      inDirectory:customFolder
                                  forLocalization:localeIdentifier]
```

Comment: make sure you are copying the file `Localizable.strings`. You should find it in Target=>"Build Phases"=>"copy bundle Resources"

Comment: is your custom folder in a specific localization folder, like /french.lproj/? because you are using `forLocalization`

Comment: Yes, under contents folder I have en.lproj with the Localizable.strings.  I intentionally want this en.lproj to be separated from the regular one as this is being used for a different purpose.

Comment: Can you try putting your contents folder in the en.lproj folder instead of doing it the other way around? I think it may not be finding it because of that.

Comment: Also, if your file is localized correctly, you should not have to call  `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:forLocalization:`, try `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:` instead

Comment: @simpleBob Do I need to use folder reference or regular folder group?

Comment: @simpleBob I cannot contents folder inside of en.lproj.  I don't want this file to be used by the app UI.  The localizable content is being used for API purpose only.

Comment: you really should rather use the `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:` method. In case you want to try the other solution, it does not matter, since only what is on the file system (not in the project) will be important.

Comment: @simpleBob Your suggestion is incorrect.  If you copy files into the Build Phase, those files will appear in the project.  Merely use pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory: won't be enough because the files won't get included into the final bundle.

Comment: @simpleBob I tried a combination of your suggestion (referenced folder + pathForResources:ofType:inDirectory) and it works.  Thank you - you can list your answer below and I will accept.